# Property file could not be resolved

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have 2 maven modules - `Webapp` and `Persistence`. Persistence module has a property file - `database.properties` and two context files - `persistenceContext.xml` (main), `datasourceContext.xml` (imported to `persistenceContext.xml`).

*persistenceContext.xml*

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.persistence"/>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties, classpath:application.properties" />

<import resource="classpath:datasourceContext.xml" />
```

Files `persistenceContext.xml, datasourceContext.xml`  and `database.properties` are in directory `resources` of `Persistence` module.

*datasourceContext.xml*

```
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close"
          class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="true"/>
    <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="20"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50"/>
    <property name="maxStatements" value="50"/>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="120"/>
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="1200"/>
 </bean>
```

*database.properties*

```
database.url=jdbc:mysql://255.255.255.255:3306/...
database.username=...
database.password=...
```

`Persistence` maven module is dependency of `Webapp` module. When I deploy `Webapp` to Tomcat it failed with exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [spring-datasource.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'database.url' in string value "${database.url}"
```

I tried the following solutions:

1. moved database.properties under directory path `resources\com\example\persistence`.
2. use `property-placeholder` or `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in `datasourceContext.xml` instead of using `property-placeholder` in `persistenceContext.xml`.
3. moved database.properties under `Webapp` module and then try point 1.
4. I always convinced that `database.properties` file is under classpath of `Persistence` module.

Nothing from mentioned doesn't work, I looked also on other threads on stackoverflow and spring forum - but with no success.

Comment: try `classpath*:` instead of `classpath:`.Also make sure that you don't have multiple `<context:property-placeholder />` as those will interfere with each other.

Comment: Please attach the output of `mvn dependency:resolve` in your webapp module, as well as a directory tree of the persistence module.

Comment: can be used only one `<context:property-placeholder />` per application? I have two `<context:property-placeholder />` - one in `Webapp` module and another in `Persistence` module.

Comment: When you have multiple XML elements, you're creating multiple placeholders, and the second one replaces the first. With Java configuration, you can instead have multiple `@PropertySource` annotations, and they add entries to the same placeholder.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was multiple using of `<context:property-placeholder />`. Please @M. Deinum, send your comment like answer.